# How to make Servicestack serialize an implicit string overload the way I want it to?

Tags: servicestack

I have a small class which I am using to make sure the strings sent and received by a service remain URL safe without additional encoding (see below).

Ideally I would like to just apply this type to my DTOs and have Servicestack be smart enough to use the implicit operators.

```
public class MyDto {
    Base64UrlString myString;
}

var dto = new MyDto() { myString = "hello i am url safe"; }
```

On the client this is received as `myString: {}`

Is there a more elegant way to do this? I had hoped applying a type this way would "just work"

```
// used only for Base64UrlEncoder
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace MyDto.ServiceModel.Types
{
    public class Base64UrlString
    {
        private readonly string _base64UrlString;

        public Base64UrlString(string str)
        {
            _base64UrlString = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(str);
        }

        public static implicit operator string(Base64UrlString base64UrlString) => base64UrlString.ToString();
        public static implicit operator Base64UrlString(string str) => new(str);

        public override string ToString() => Base64UrlEncoder.Decode(_base64UrlString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change your class to a **struct** to make use of the [custom struct behavior](https://docs.servicestack.net/json-format#using-structs-to-customize-json) you're trying to use in your example.

Also ServiceStack.Text serializers only serializes **public properties** by default so your DTO should use public properties:

```cs
public class MyDto {
    public Base64UrlString MyString { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively you can configure it to serialize public fields with:

```cs
JsConfig.Init(new Config {
    IncludePublicFields = true
});
```

Comment: Thanks @mythz, but it looks like what I'm trying to do might not be possible - basically I want any "string" which is of type Base64UrlString to leave my service as a base64 encoded string and when it returns (as a base64 encoded string) to be read by the service as a decoded string.

I can see the functions in my struct being called but ParseJson isn't unless I explicitly call "str.FromJson<Base64UrlString>()"

Comment: @JanMartin overriding ToString() controls serialization which you can deserialize with a string constructor, alternatively you can just store utf8 in byte[] which already has this behavior in text serializers

Comment: I've just had a look at how it works with byte[] - am I correct in thinking that what I will have to do is in my ToString function, check if the value is encoded, and if so, decode it and vice versa? There is no way to tell from inside the type whether its being sent or received?

Comment: Here's my ToString() function that "works" unless the value is actually a base64 string... public override string ToString()
        {
            try
            {
                return Base64UrlEncoder.Decode(Value);
            }
            catch { }

            return Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(Value);
        } - only problem is that if I use the servicestack JsonApiClient it ends up getting encoded on the server and decoded by the client!

Comment: @JanMartin I was proposing just using `byte[]` (i.e. without any custom class) since it has built-in support in text serializers to encode/decode as Base64. Structs constructor should be used to deserialize/parse the serialized string value whilst ToString() should be used to encode/serialize it, looks like you're trying to do the inverse.